# How to open Windows Explorer via link

Tags: html

I am trying to make a link in an email that will open Windows Explorer and go directly to the given path. I have tried `<a href="file:remoteservername/C:/folder1/folder2/folder3">Link</a>`, but it opens Internet Explorer and does not open that path.

Comment: I doubt that there is a standards conforming way to generate an URL that works on all major mail clients and just opens the Windows Explorer (or worse: runs any other program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got it. My mistake was that I wrote whole path to the folder. That wasn't necessary. All I had to do was `"file://///servername/folder3` and not `"file://///servername/folder1/folder2/folder3"`. Thanks for all your suggestions and comments.