# Folder opening using html

Tags: html, href

So I am creating an offline webpage in which I have to make Html open a folder.
This is the code I am using

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="file:///C:\Users\Hi\Desktop\Bro">Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is not working,any changes which can make it work??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link to a file share through an anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474702/link-to-a-file-share-through-an-anchor-tag)

Comment: nope @WardSegers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, window.open method of javascript worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="C:\Users\youruserName\Desktop\yourfile">open</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598232/how-to-open-windows-explorer-via-link

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
file:///C:/Users/Hi/Desktop/Bro